# sudden long horizontal scrollbar, tried several solutions incl. "overflow: hidden" but to no avail

Tags: scrollbar, overflow, wordpress-theming

I suddenly got this long horizontal scrollbar on my Wordpress blog that uses the theme "Wave" by Themeforest, [here](http://alkotab.net).

The scrollbar did not appear before, so it is not an issue with the original theme (I mean I can't blame the theme).
 I deactivated latest plugins that I thought could be the reason, but no help.
I added the overflow: hidden; to my body class (I have no wrapper class) but that disabled also the vertical scroll which prevented the rest of the site from being displayed.

I checked the width properties, they are fine.

I have validated both the CSS and the HTML codes, and fixed minor things that were there. Yet the problem is still there !!

I removed 3 pages from the nav (to see perhaps having many of them is what causes the problem).

All that, did not fix the problem !

I should mention that the widget causing it is the Polldaddy poll in the right sidebar. When I remove it, the scroll is gone. I emailed Polldaddy support and they reviewed my theme and even installed it on their own system, but found nothing that counterfeits with their poll !

I replaced the current theme files with the original theme templates: the php templates, CSS files and JS files (including the nav.js).
That didn't change anything.

What could it be?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a combination of two CSS properties contributing to the problem which is causing the scrollbar:

```
<div id="stwrapper" class="stwrapper" style="visibility: hidden; top: -999px; left: -999px;">
<div id="SwfStore_swfstore_0" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -2000px;">
```

By removing both `left: -...px;` attributes the horizontal scrollbar should disappear.

Comment: Thank you Christian, really appreciate ur help. I am not sure where you found these. I looked into my CSS.
There is only one propery containing "999", that is:
z-index: 999;
Note that it does not have "left"
I did not find any CSS property that contains "2000", at all !
I further did not find any "stwrapper" or "SwfStore_swfstore", not even in the page's source file. 
So where do you see them?
BTW, I never missed with any "lef: -xxx" values, so if they are there, they are there with the theme originally, and the t=theme used to work fine without the scrollbar, so what caused the issue?

Comment: Hi again, the CSS was inside the HTML, maybe inserted by JavaScript so that it was not easily visible inside the plain HTML: stwrapper is the last element before </body>, SwfStore_... is inside #mid #mid-inner #sidebar-right #text-9 .textwidget #PD_superContainer. Can't tell where these come from, maybe you can now. Try adding the following to your CSS file to override these settings - at least as a workaround: `#stwrapper, #SwfStore_swfstore_0 {left: 0px !important}`

Comment: Okay. From what you've given me it seems its is in one text sidebar.. and that is indeed the case because the scroll appears only when the Polldaddy poll widget is activated (where I put the poll JAVA code inside a text widget).. (you can see the widget in the website: http://alkotab.net/) .

So can I safely say it is indeed caused by the widget? 
The problem is that a developer at Polldaddy (the poll hosting service) said he checked and made sure the error does not originate in their side, and that he installed same poll in same widget in the same theme of mine, and he did not have the error!

Comment: BTW, with the solution you suggested, the long scroll is gone, but the scrollbar it self is still appearing, though almost not scrolling

Comment: The widget causes this because it is not compatible for use with `direction: rtl;`. Try it: remove the `left: 0px !important` and set `body{direction:ltr !important}` instead which switches your whole document to ltr. The scrollbar is gone, too. Polldaddy didn't test with this direction setting but should do so with their HTML set to `body{direction:rtl !important}`. The `direction` interferes with the `left` setting so they have to check for existing `direction` and set `left` value accordingly.

Comment: I only get a vertical scrollbar unless I resize my browser window so that the page elements won't fit the width. You still have a barely movable horizontal scrollbar? Can you tell me your browser/display resolution? The browser´s viewport needs to have a width of at least `1119px` for not showing a horizontal scrollbar (caused by your page's elements).

Comment: Thank you again Christian. With 
#stwrapper, #SwfStore_swfstore_0 {left: 0px !important}
The scroll disappeared from Chrome (it appears but it does not scroll.. its just there, with default (100%) page size) but remained in IE

With direction: rtl; it disappeared from IE and appeared in Chrome.

With both of them, it seems the scroll dissappears from all browsers, except that in Chrome it displays as I described above, the scroll bar is there , but it does not actually scroll (though it moves like 3 pixels only) 

USING latest versions of all of them.
But I was basically concerned about IE